# My angular app cannot be deployed to heroku. How do I fix this?

Tags: angular, heroku

I've created an angular app that I want to deploy to heroku but the build has been failing. I've followed the steps provided from https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147 and I haven't gotten it to work. What changes are needed to make this work?

```
Here's my build log

-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  v10.16.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.9.0

       Resolving node version v10.16.3...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
       npm 6.9.0 already installed with node

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_4cf23a391f9c002e9d1c85d30acc96ae/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > core-js@3.2.1 postinstall /tmp/build_4cf23a391f9c002e9d1c85d30acc96ae/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_4cf23a391f9c002e9d1c85d30acc96ae/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > @angular/cli@8.3.9 postinstall /tmp/build_4cf23a391f9c002e9d1c85d30acc96ae/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js


       > bjornlidenfix@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_4cf23a391f9c002e9d1c85d30acc96ae
       > ng build --aot -prod

       Unknown option: '-d'
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! bjornlidenfix@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot -prod`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the bjornlidenfix@0.0.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.00JQ7/_logs/2019-10-13T16_59_55_855Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "bjornliden",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "contentful": "^7.10.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: --prod, not -prod

Comment: Does running `ng build —aot —prod` (Double dashes) locally build before trying to deploy to heroku?

Comment: I get "ERROR in src/app/contentful.service.ts:9:24 - error TS2339: Property 'contentful' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

9     space: environment.contentful.spaceId,
                         ~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/contentful.service.ts:10:30 - error TS2339: Property 'contentful' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

10     accessToken: environment.contentful.token"

Comment: you need to fix such errors before deploying

Comment: I fixed the erros and I now deploy successfully but instead of showing the content on the site it only says "Not Found"

Answer (score -1):

The resource you provided gives an alternative to the postinstall command.

Try replacing:

```
"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
```

with this:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
```

Comment: first one is a typo anyway, should be --prod

Comment: The build is still failing